# How to open Menu only on long press gesture SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there a way to show context menu on long press gesture in SwiftUI?

I have a code like this:

```
Text(messageModel.message)
  .padding(.vertical,8)
  .padding(.horizontal,12)
  .background(Constants.clientMessageColor)
  .foregroundColor(Color.black)
  .cornerRadius(20, corners: [.topLeft,.bottomLeft,.topRight, .bottomRight])
  .onTapGesture {
       self.isExpanded.toggle()
       self.isClientNameVisible.toggle()
  }
  .contextMenu {
       Button(action: {
                                        
       }) {
             Text("Normal Colors")
             Image(systemName: "paintbrush")
       }
   }
```

And also I use Menu in SwiftUI and also don't know how to show in long press.

My code look like this:

```
Menu() {
    Button("Order Now", action: {})
    Button("Adjust Order", action: {})
    Button("Cancel", action: {})
} label : {
    Text("HELLO")
        .onLongPressGesture {
            // Show menu when this triggers
        }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a simple demo (for clarity, `menuItems` extracted outside the `body`):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("On long press")
                .contextMenu {
                    menuItems
                }
            Menu("On tap") {
                menuItems
            }
        }
    }
    
    var menuItems: some View {
        Group {
            Button("Action 1", action: {})
            Button("Action 2", action: {})
            Button("Action 3", action: {})
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

They added a primaryAction call for iOS 15+

This is the sample code from the documentation

```
Menu {
    Button(action: addCurrentTabToReadingList) {
        Label("Add to Reading List", systemImage: "eyeglasses")
    }
    Button(action: bookmarkAll) {
        Label("Add Bookmarks for All Tabs", systemImage: "book")
    }
    Button(action: show) {
        Label("Show All Bookmarks", systemImage: "books.vertical")
    }
} label: {
    Label("Add Bookmark", systemImage: "book")
} primaryAction: {
    addBookmark()
}
```

The primary action will be performed when the user taps or clicks on the body of the control, and the menu presentation will happen on a secondary gesture, such as on long press or on click of the menu indicator.