# Enable menu when long pressing on URL

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a string with URLs inside and I show it like this:

```
Text(LocalizedStringKey(
    "Multiple URLs here, such as https://stackoverflow.com"
    + " or https://www.google.com"
))
```

The URLs are highlighted correctly and I can tap to open them, but I can't long press a single one to e.g. copy the URL or ideally provide some custom actions.

Is that possible and if so how do I do that?

---

Edit:
I also tried splitting the text into tokens and combining `Text` Views, but adding a `.contextMenu` doesn't work there:

```
Text("Multiple URLs here, such as ")
    + Text(LocalizedStringKey("https://stackoverflow.com"))
        .contextMenu { } // < Cannot convert value of type 'some View' to expected argument type 'Text'
    + Text(" or ...")
```

Comment: How about adding a `contextMenu`?

Comment: What platform, iOS or macOS?

Comment: I updated the question, @JoakimDanielson it's on iOS.

Comment: @Sweeper You're right, if there's only one URL that might work (although it would trigger on everything) but I can have multiple URLs. I adjusted the question to make that more clear.

Comment: You can use LongPressureGesture with a menu. Like this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64277962/how-to-open-menu-only-on-long-press-gesture-swiftui

Comment: Off topic but its better to add definitions like SwiftUI and iOS as tags instead of listing them in the title

Comment: @JoakimDanielson how would I detect which URL was long pressed?

Comment: I guess I could filter out the URLs myself and then stich everything together with custom contextMenus, but that sound's like a not-ideal solution. I'd have to detect the URLs myself which has the potential to be wrong, I'd rather let the system do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try the following. I've thought of a **tokenizer** that splits every URL in the string you pass to the `Text`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let textWithUrls = "Visit https://stackoverflow1.com and https://stackoverflow2.com https://stackoverflow3.com - https://stackoverflow2.com https://stackoverflow4.com"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(textWithUrls)
                .padding()
                .contextMenu(menuItems: {
                    // Loop through URL strings
                    ForEach(getUrls(from: textWithUrls), id: \.self) { url in
                        // A View of your chosing here. I've used Button.
                        Button(action: {
                            if let url = URL(string: url) {
                                UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                            }
                        }) {
                            Text(url)
                                .padding()
                        }
                    }
                })

            
        }
    }

    // Function to extract URLs from the text using regular expression
    private func getUrls(from text: String) -> [String] {
        do {
            let detector = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
            let matches = detector.matches(in: text, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count))
            return matches.compactMap { $0.url?.absoluteString }
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
            return []
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried separating the string using spaces, words and dashes and it has always worked. The `getUrls` **function** uses a regular expression to dectect URLs and returns them as an array of String.

Here's the result:

[image: Context menu tokenized URLs]

**Edit:** If your URLs are way to many to be handled by the contextMenu you could try something like this:

```
ForEach(getUrls(from: textWithUrls), id: \.self) { url in
     Button(action: {
         if let url = URL(string: url) {
             UIApplication.shared.open(url)
         }
         }) {
            Text(url)
                .padding(4)
        }
    }
```

Let me know if you like this solution!

Comment: The problem is there could be a lot more links and it would get confusing quickly.

Comment: I've updated the code. Would that be good? You could add a contextMenu to the View inside the ForEach if you want to add some more actions of course.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I'm trying to have the context menu on the actual link, not on the entire text which gets messy quickly and is a weird user experience. I'd prefer letting the user tap the link and use Safari's share sheet in that case

Comment: Ok, I get it. At least I've learnt a new thing by doing this, how to split URLs in a string.

Comment: Have a look at the code in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78019300/swift-ui-make-clickable-a-hashtag-preceding-a-word as soon as I've seen it I recalled this question of yours. Maybe it could be good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ReadOnlyDetectableLinkTextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var text: String
    var dataDetectorTypes: UIDataDetectorTypes = .all
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.linkTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.link]
        //act like SwiftUI.Text()
        textView.isSelectable = true
        textView.isEditable = false
        textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        textView.dataDetectorTypes = .link
        //Avoid destroying pop-up animations
        textView.clipsToBounds = false
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ReadOnlyDetectableLinkTextView(text: "请访问 https://www.apple.com 以获取更多信息 https://google.com")
            .frame(height: 40) // 可根据实际文本内容调整高度
            .padding()
    }
}
```

You can use

```
Text("ABCD")
.overylay { ReadOnlyDetectableLinkTextView(text: "ABCD") }
```

to make right、dynamic frame size.